# Symfony 4 form checkbox with URL in label

Tags: symfony, symfony4

This should be something simple, but I still don't get it ...

How can I render a form with a label that contains a URL ON THE SAME LINE!

[image]

With something like this I get the label under the checkbox...

```
{% set terms_link %}<a title="{% trans %}Read the General Terms and Conditions{% endtrans %}"
                       href="{{ path('homepage') }}">{% trans %}General Terms and Conditions{% endtrans %}</a>{% endset %}
{% set general_terms_and_conditions %}{{ 'I have read and accept the %general_terms_and_conditions%.'|trans({ '%general_terms_and_conditions%': terms_link })|raw }}{% endset %}
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.agreeTerms.vars.id }}">{{ general_terms_and_conditions|raw }}</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this searching the internet maybe it can help.

twig.vue

```
{% set termsOfUseFormGroup %}
   {{ form_row(registrationForm.consentement) }}
{% endset %}
{{ termsOfUseFormGroup|replace({'#DOCUMENTATION#':'<a class="has-text-underline" href="' ~ absolute_url(path('donnees_personnelles')) ~ '">documentation RGPD</a>'})|raw }}
```

formType

```
->add('consentement',CheckboxType::class,[
    'constraints' => [
        new IsTrue(['message' => 'Avez-vu lu notre politique de traitement de données ?'])
    ],
    'mapped' => false, // pour ne pas lier le consentement à la base de données
    'required' => false,
    'label' => 'Je confirme avoir lu la #DOCUMENTATION# concernant le traitement de mes données personnelles.'
])
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Symfony 5 Symfony has a new option for form labels called 'label_html'. Just set it to true. Might be worth doing the upgrade considering Symfony 4 is end of life in a couple of months anyway (november 2022).

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#label-html

```php
$builder->add(
    'terms_and_conditions',
    CheckboxType::class,
    [
        'required' => true,
        'label' => 'I accept the <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#terms">terms and conditions</a>',
        'label_html' => true,
        'constraints' => [
            New Constraints\NotBlank()
        ]
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap both elements into `<div>` and set its style to `display:flex`.

See how the flexbox works [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).